# JS Class property "is undefined" even tho it appears to be defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, undefined

I'm quite new to JS and I'm trying to do a TicTacToe game with a custom size board in an attempt to learn a bit more. I first coded just a 3x3 version and started building up from there.

Right as I got past the point where I have a custom grid size entered right after loading the page and the grid rendering, I started getting the same problem when trying to click any cell to try and play a turn.

> "this.game_state[clicked_cell_i] is undefined".

I have tried opening up F12 and checking if the game_state array (which is a 2d array of strings that tracks which cell is played and which isn't) but when I do everything seems normal and the array gets printed out without problem. (picture showcases printing out the game_state array in a 4x4 grid) https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV0pY.png

I would really appreciate it if somebody could explain to me what's happening or even better - help me fix it. Thanks :)

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/z8649pxL

````
class game {
    status_display;
    is_game_active;
    curr_player;
    game_state;

    constructor() {
        this.status_display = document.querySelector('.status');
        this.is_game_active = true;
        this.curr_player = "X";
        this.game_state = matrix(rows, rows, "");
    }

    cell_played(clicked_cell, clicked_cell_i, clicked_cell_j){
        this.game_state[clicked_cell_i][clicked_cell_j] = this.curr_player;
        clicked_cell.innerHTML = this.curr_player;
        if(this.curr_player === "X"){
            document.getElementById((i*rows)+j).style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        } else if(this.curr_player === "O"){
            document.getElementById((i*rows)+j).style.backgroundColor = "#33ccff";
        }
    }

    cell_click(clicked_cellEvent){
        debugger
        const clicked_cell = clicked_cellEvent.target;
        let clicked_cell_i = parseInt(clicked_cell.getAttribute('i'));
        let clicked_cell_j = parseInt(clicked_cell.getAttribute('j'));
        if(this.game_state[clicked_cell_i][clicked_cell_j] !== "" || !this.is_game_active) {
            return;
        }
        this.cell_played(clicked_cell, clicked_cell_i, clicked_cell_j);
        this.res_validation();
    }
};

let ex_game = new game();

function create_grid() {
    document.getElementById('hidestart').style.display = "none";
    var Container = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");
    Container.innerHTML = '';
    
    rows = prompt("n?");
    let i = 0, j = 0;
      
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--columns-row", rows);
    for (i = 0; i < rows ; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "cell";
            div.id = (i*rows)+j;
            div.setAttribute("cell-index", (i*rows)+j);
            div.setAttribute("i", i);
            div.setAttribute("j", j);
            let wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");
            wrapper[0].appendChild(div);
        }
    }
    document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        ex_game.cell_click(e);
        e.stopPropagation();
    }));
    document.getElementById('hidestart').style.display = "block";
}

function matrix(rows, cols, defaultValue){
    var arr = [];
    // Creates all lines:
    for(var i=0; i < rows; i++){
        // Creates an empty line
        arr.push([]);
        // Adds cols to the empty line:
        arr[i].push(new Array(cols));
        for(var j=0; j < cols; j++){
          // Initializes:
          arr[i][j] = defaultValue;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}```
````

Comment: `rows` is missing. I assume you define it elsewhere globally, which is bad structuring, since your class *alone* is incomplete.

Comment: Yes, rows is a global. For some reason when I go to edit its there, but in the post its missing..

Comment: So this.game_state[clicked_cell_i] is undefined inside cell_click function?

Comment: You should make it part of the class and pass it in the `constructor()`. Even if the way you do it works, you can see the issue now by it not being there since it is not part of the class structure ifself.

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani correct

Comment: @Lain I'm also using it in different functions too thats why its public. I posted a jsfiddle in the comment under the first reply if you want to see the code in its entirity

Comment: Also be aware that your `rows` is a string and not a number, due to `rows = prompt("n?");`, Should change it to `rows = Number(prompt("n?"));`

Comment: Have you tried logging what is "this" inside cell_click function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
new game()
```

the  constructor is been called of that class.
And in that constructor you are calling **matrix** which requires the value of rows.
But initially the class do not have any value.

So the state is not getting initialized at that point of time.
That why when you use the array, it is getting undefined.

So to resolve this issue, you could just try to get the object of class **game** after getting the rows from user, and pass that rows in the arguments when calling the constructor of the class.

```
let ex_game = new game(rows);
```

And then using this argument call the function matrix.

Edit:

I have looked into your code.
The error is in the method called **cell_played**. you are using i and j which are not known to it. Please replace your code with following line. This would resolve your error.

```
  cell_played(clicked_cell, clicked_cell_i, clicked_cell_j){
      this.game_state[clicked_cell_i][clicked_cell_j] = this.curr_player;
        clicked_cell.innerHTML = this.curr_player;
        if(this.curr_player === "X"){
            document.getElementById((clicked_cell_i*rows)+clicked_cell_j).style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        } else if(this.curr_player === "O"){
        document.getElementById((clicked_cell_i*rows)+clicked_cell_j).style.backgroundColor = "#33ccff";
        }
    }
```

And also remove the parameter **rows** from constructor and just call the constructor after taking the number of rows from user.

```
let ex_game

function create_grid() {
    /* document.getElementById('hidestart').style.display = "none" */
    var Container = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");
    Container.innerHTML = '';
    rows = prompt("n?");
    let i = 0, j = 0;
    ex_game= new game().........
```

Comment: Rows is a global var, defined by a prompt when loading the page for the first time, theyre not in the class.

Comment: okay then just write the new game() in the fuction called create_grid()

Comment: Tried that and what you said after editing ur reply, the problem still persists

Comment: What have you tried, can you please share your code using some editor, so that it could be more specific.

Comment: I have added the edit in the answer please look into that.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: I already did, but since Im a new user its not visible to the public :)